# Issue to open dialog: Yii

Tags: yii, dialog

I have used ajaxSubmitButton in my form.On click of button i am trying to open dialog When i click the button ,the dialog opens and it displays entire code written for that form . How to resolve this?

my code for button is :

```
<div class="btnalign" style="margin-top: 20px;margin-left:20px;">

    <?=CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Mail to Client', Yii::app()->createUrl('reply/composeMail'),
        array('type'=>'POST',
              'data'=> 'js:{"data1":callData()}',
            //'success' => 'function(response){afterSubmitForm(response);}'
              'success'=>'js:function(string){ alert(string);$.fn.yiiGridView.update("my-grid"); }'
        ),

        array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'));
    ?>

</div>
```

> my controller code:

```
public function actionComposeMail()
{
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){ 
    print_r($_POST['data1']);
        if(isset($_POST['data1'])){
            $model=new Reply;
            $model->scenario = 'compose';

            EQuickDlgs::render('_compose',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            ));
            }else{
            echo "Please select row to Mail.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The request is invalid.";
    }
}
```

> my dialog form code is:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'reply-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'), 
 )); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.For multiple recipients please seperate by comma</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>



<div class="row col2">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_from'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email_from',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'readonly'=>'readonly')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email_from'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row col2">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_to'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email_to',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>150)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email_to'); ?>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div class="row col2">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email_cc'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email_cc',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>250)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email_cc'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row col2">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'subject'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'subject',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>250)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'subject'); ?>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'message'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'message',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'message'); ?>
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Send' :         'Send',array('class' => 'btn')); ?>
  </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

> Image of dialog

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use `renderPartial()` instead of `render()` and try to call `Yii::app()->end()` at the end in your mail form view

```
public function actionComposeMail()
{
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){ 
    print_r($_POST['data1']);
        if(isset($_POST['data1'])){
            $model=new Reply;
            $model->scenario = 'compose';

            $this->renderPartial('_compose',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            ));
            }else{
            echo "Please select row to Mail.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "The request is invalid.";
    }
}
```

Comment: see updated code... Forgot to use `$this` while renderPartial